# Get error when I want to display detail in new activity after click on RecyclerView. Using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I would like the `ViewProduct` activity to show the detail of the item clicked on the `recyclerView`. My aim later is to change the `textView` to a `editText` to edit the products, but for now I would like it to show.

My problem is filling the `textView` with the data from the particular product from Firebase.

You will see there is a toast message that is commented out which works and show the position, so I know I am on the right track somehow. Now the app just crashes if I click on the item, giving error:

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

All I need now is to populate the `textfield`s with the data from Firebase.

Here is my itemView in my RecyclerAdapter:

```
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                //Toast.makeText(context,"Position"+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                    //listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                    listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position),(position));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), ViewProduct.class);
                    intent.putExtra("product_ID:", position);
                    itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        });
```

And here is my ViewProduct Activity where I want to see the details:
public class ViewProduct extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private String edit_product_ID;

private TextView mProduct, mPrice;
private TextView mSave, mDelete;

private DatabaseReference product_ref;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.view_product);

product_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ultra_liquors");

edit_product_ID = getIntent().getExtras().get("product_ID").toString();


    //Toast.makeText(this, "The Product ID:" + edit_product_ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product);
    mPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
    mSave = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.save);
    mDelete = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.delete);

    RetrieveProductInfo();

}

private void RetrieveProductInfo() {
    product_ref.child(edit_product_ID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild(edit_product_ID))) {
                String product_name = dataSnapshot.child("product").getValue().toString();
                String product_price = dataSnapshot.child("price").getValue().toString();

                mProduct.setText(product_name);
                mPrice.setText(product_price);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: At which particular line of code does the error occur? Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: ViewProduct line 45 edit_product_ID = getIntent().getExtras().get("product_ID").toString();

Comment: `intent.putExtra("product_ID:", position);`
Should be replaced with `intent.putExtra("product_ID", position);`
You have a ":"-symbol in the string

Answer (score 1):

The string in `intent.putExtra("product_ID:", position);` has a trailing colon-symbol behind it. which causes `getExtras().get(...)` to return null. null.toString() throws the error

Comment: thank you. I am making progress. Now at least it is opening the activity, but it does not populate the textViews.

Comment: Are you sure that the lines of code where you call .setText are actually being called?

Comment: No it doesn't. But before that it looks like I am not getting the data from Firebase. And to be honest I don't think I know how to that, so maybe some help or a pointer to a good tutorial will do. Please

Comment: It can be many reasons. I would start by adding a log output in onCancelled. Something like Log.d("firebaseError", error.getMessage());
Also, in the onDataChange-method, add an else-statement after the if to also log output, to confirm whether it gets triggered or not.
From what I understand, also make sure that your firebase database has a setup of:
`"ultra_liquors": { <product_id> : { product: <astring>, price: <astring> }}`

Comment: Your setup with firebase might be wrong, or your test-device (your mobile or emulator) may not be connected to internet. The logs might give you an indication. I would also suggest trying to debug the code with breakpoints on a couple of lines to see that all the values are set to expected values

Answer (score 0):

Add this line with Intent

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

I think that was the issue try it and let me know!

Comment: I'm sorry it does the same, but I saw a error @Andreas pointed out and now at least it is showing the new acticity but it is not populating the textViews with the data from Firebase. Thank you so far.

Comment: are you getting the values ?? like you passed through the intent

Comment: You can see on line 144 I created a toast message (which is canncelled ou now), that worked, it showed the position in the toast, hence I am saying I think I am on the right track. 
//Toast.makeText(context,"Position"+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: I think you the data are null that's why it didn't display.try to log the values of getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position) and position and try to add log in RetrieveProductInfo() if (dataSnapshot.exists()

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, so maybe some help please. And thank you for your help so far.